# How to train the background removal (rembg) model our images

Tags: computer-vision

does anyone know, how to train the rembg  model with our own images  and save it into Pickel file
This is rembg model:
https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg
please help me, How to train the above model.

Answer (score 2):

The model provided simply uses a [U^2-Net Model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.09007.pdf) to predict a mask of pixels indicating whether a pixel is the background or foreground. The github readme links to an [existing python implementation in pytorch](https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net), which is from the original authors of the paper. This also contains the training script they used called `u2net_train.py`. If you want to train this model yourself you need to make sure that you have pairs of images with one image being the original/input image and the other being a mask indicating which pixels are the foreground and background. You can then either use the existing implementation (by making some adjustments to the script) or write a training loop yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm digging up this post because I (finally) stumbled upon what would make a good base for a proper howto train your own rembg model.
It's a post by endh1337in Daniel Gatis's rembg Github.
https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg/issues/193#issuecomment-1055534289

As per Internet Rule #35, I'd be glad to make a proper howto as soon as I have this procedure personally reviewed and tested.
Meanwhile, I hope it helps at least someone!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/81086)